# Different kinds of PowerShell console being launched

Tags: windows-7, powershell, console

I am on Windows 7, and when I launch a PowerShell console, depending on the situation, I get one of two kinds of prompts, as shown in the screen capture.  The one on the right (with navy background) is the one I have customized.  What I don't understand is why I get the prompt on the left (DOS-like terminal console with stock black background).

The left prompt (DOS-like) is launched when I right-click on one of the "favorites" folders in the Windows Explorer's left pane and select "PowerShell Prompt Here".

The right one (customized) is launched when I right-click on any other folder in Windows Explorer's left pane and select "PowerShell Prompt Here".

What should I do to always get the customized prompt?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell's visual settings are defined by the shortcut that points to it, so if you use the link from the start menu, it appears as it does on the right, but if you launch powershell from cmd, or start -> run (or any 3rd party tool), it will use the defaults that cmd uses.

see this article for more details and instructions for setting the style globally for your specific user. if you want to runas a powershell, you will have to modify the runas users styles as well.

http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2008/06/01/powershells-noble-blue/

Comment: My recommendation is to start launching "ConEmu" instead ;) it's an awesome console "replacement" and among it's many features: it lets you set colors based on the process that's running, and you can resize it by just resizing the window ;) http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/